# angularjs boolean php post callback

Tags: php, angularjs, http

is there a solution to get **boolean** response from **php** **post** method using **angularjs** **controller**!!!

I tried this solution and returned boolean type from php code and it doesn't work

[image: Code]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please go through http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking. And please don't post text/code as images...

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are "returning" response from php by outputing the string "true", for example

```
echo "true";
```

in this case, the server you are using adds content-type http header, which is probably text/plain in this case.

To get it to work, you can set
    header('Content-Type: application/json');

true should be a valid JSON value. Hovewer, using application/json content gives you a more options.

You can send a whole object using this method! But i'll leave that to you.

By using proper Content-Type, your boolean should be automaticaly proccesed.

In the javascript side, checking your response.data should be just fine.

Hovewer if you do not want to add content-type header in your php, you should write your condition like this

```
if(response.data == "true") //or better use ===
```

Why? Because right now you are probably evaluating string - which is always true.

I hope that i got you right, because it is hard to answer if you are not posting your php code, and better explanation of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot respond with direct boolean value, in this case you can send a json object containing the response just like this :

**Server side :**

```
<?php

// inform the client about the content-type of this response in order to parse it automatically
header('Content-Type: application/json');

// send a json encoded array
echo json_encode(array(
  "boolean_value" => true,
  "other_data" => "something else if you want..."
));

?>
```

**Client side :**

```
...
function(response){
  if(response.data.boolean_value == true){
    ...
  }else{
    ...
  }
}
...
```